# C++ Write a function called display

Tags: c++

I have this problem. **Write a function called display. The function has an integer parameter that is positive. It prints a
diagram with horizontal bars to display the digits of the parameter starting from the first digit at the top. Each bar
should show numbers that count from 1 to the digit being displayed. If the parameter is not positive your function
should not print anything. Excessively long solutions that use more than 10 lines of code may lose points.
For example, a program that uses the function follows.**

I want to make the function recursive. What am I doing wrong here?

```
#include <iostream>

int display(int x) {
    if (x<=0) return 0;
    if (x<10) {
        for (int i =1; i<=x; i++) {
            std::cout << i;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    else
        return display(x/10)+x%10;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    display(31415);
    return 0;
}
```

This should produce the following output:

```
123
1
1234
1
12345
```

but instead it just displays

```
123
```

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: learn to use your debugger

Comment: [Your Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) would like you to explain to it what is returned when `x` is less than 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your display function will be recursively called with 31415, 3141, 314, 31 and then finally 3 and then your `for` loop will do

```
for (int i =1; i<=x /*3*/; i++) {
    std::cout << i;
}
```

which will then print 123.